# Changing an image while click is held

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, onmousedown, onmouseup

I am looking to change an image of a button from when a click is held, then change back upon click release. I currently have a flat image, and I want it to change to one with an inner-shadow to make it look like a button press, but change back to the original flat image when the mouse click is released. I tried onmouseup but I think i'm using it incorrectly. I want the `"item"` and `"item2"` to hold their image when clicked, and that works correctly. However I want the `"item3"` to change back upon mouse release, or just change back instantly after being clicked.

(Edit: I'm new to JavaScript, it doesn't have to be an `onmouseup` solution. If someone can explain how to create a function which does this then that would be great.)

**JS:**

```
var onImgStp= "images/stop.png";
var onImgPnk= "images/pink.png";
var onImgMut= "images/mute.png";
var offImg= "images/green.png";
var offImgStp= "images/stop2.png";
```

**HTML:**

```
<img class="item" src="images/pink.png" onclick="manage(1); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgPnk : offImg);"/>
<img class="item" src="images/pink.png" onclick="manage(2); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgPnk : offImg);"/>
<img class="item" src="images/pink.png" onclick="manage(3); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgPnk : offImg);"/>
<img class="item" src="images/pink.png" onclick="manage(4); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgPnk : offImg);"/>
<img class="item" src="images/pink.png" onclick="manage(5); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgPnk : offImg);"/>
<img class="item" src="images/pink.png" onclick="manage(6); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgPnk : offImg);"/>
<img class="item" src="images/pink.png" onclick="manage(7); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgPnk : offImg);"/>
<img class="item" src="images/pink.png" onclick="manage(8); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgPnk : offImg);"/>
<img class="item2" src="images/mute.png" onclick="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgMut : offImg);"/>
<img class="item3" src="images/stop.png" onmouseup="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImgStp)? onImgStp : offImgStp);"/>
```

Comment: The "click" event happens as a result of a mousedown/mouseup pair.

Comment: remove onclick event if you want to work with mouseup event.

Comment: I'm new to JavaScript, it doesn't have to be an `onmouseup` solution. If someone can explain how to create a function which does this then that would be great.

Comment: @NathanWilson I dont think you need javascript for that, you could just use css :active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this very simple Proof Of Concept solution (based on your question and the comments):

```js
function mousedown() {
  var el = document.getElementById("image01");
  el.setAttribute("src", "http://blog.fantasy.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/feature_Net.jpg")
}

function resetImage() {
  var el = document.getElementById("image01");
  el.setAttribute("src", "https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b87a252140848659b80b0d2297e32dc62afee0cf/68747470733a2f2f646f63732e6d6963726f736f66742e636f6d2f656e2d75732f646f746e65742f61727469636c65732f696d616765732f6875622f6e6574636f72652e737667")
}
```

```html
<img id="image01" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b87a252140848659b80b0d2297e32dc62afee0cf/68747470733a2f2f646f63732e6d6963726f736f66742e636f6d2f656e2d75732f646f746e65742f61727469636c65732f696d616765732f6875622f6e6574636f72652e737667" alt="image" onmousedown="mousedown()" onmouseup="resetImage();" onmouseleave="resetImage();" />
```

Normally I would advise to *use CSS* (and maybe stitched images if you still need more than one) to accomplish this effect.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for and works great! However with it being an `id` and not a `class` it all moves over to the right slightly. And if changed to a `class` the button press doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: The id is only needed to identify the element in the JS, and has no impact on the way these elements are rendered. You can also use a ```name``` or ```class``` to identify the image element you want to change the src for, but that would change the JS needed.

Comment: @RickvandenBosch the downside with this is that you change the src of the image all the time. So if the image doesn't get cached you will have to load it again after every event. Moreover the second image will not even start getting loaded until it's pressed.

Comment: I agree... It's showing how it could work in principle. 'cause normally I would advise to use CSS (and maybe stitched images) to accomplish this effect.

Comment: Thanks for updating

Comment: Great help/adive from everyone, thanks. I've decided to take what you said and work through this in CSS and the results are great.

Answer (score 3):

### Simple solution

```css
.image-swap {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-swap>img, .image-swap:active>img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.image-swap>img:first-child, .image-swap:active>img:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-swap">
  <img src="http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/media/city7.png" />
  <img src="http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/media/city2.png" />
</div>
```

### Remove select and drag effect

```css
.image-swap {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-swap>img {
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

.image-swap>img:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.image-swap:active>img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.image-swap:active>img:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-swap">
  <img src="http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/media/city7.png" />
  <img src="http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/media/city2.png" />
</div>
```

### Smooth transition

```css
.image-swap {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.image-swap>img {
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image-swap>img:first-child {
  position: static;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-swap:active>img:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
}

.image-swap:active>img:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-swap">
  <img src="http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/media/city7.png" />
  <img src="http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/media/city2.png" />
</div>
```

If you want you could give classes to the images like `base-img` and `active-img`

So you could replace the `:first-child` with `.base-img` and `:last-child` with `.active-img`