# Getting hover to work despite same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get my `div` element to change pictures. The problem I'm having is that all the `div` that I've selected are changing. I've tried the .each() function but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```js
$('.product_category_item div').hover(function() {
  $('.main_image').each(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
  });

  $('.hover_image').each(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "block");
  });
}, function() {
  $('.main_image').each(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "block");
  });

  $('.hover_image').each(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 product_category_item">
  <a href="taps.html">
    <div>
      <img class="main_image" src="img/water-faucet1.jpg">
      <img class="hover_image" src="img/gold-faucet1.jpg">
      <p>
        taps
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 product_category_item">
  <div>
    <img class="main_image" src="img/block_seal.jpg">
    <img class="hover_image" src="img/round_seal.jpg">

    <p>
      seals
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 product_category_item">
  <div>
    <img class="main_image" src="img/hinge1.jpg">
    <img class="hover_image" src="img/hinge2.jpg">

    <p>
      hinges
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 product_category_item">
  <div>
    <img class="main_image" src="img/handle1.jpg">
    <img class="hover_image" src="img/handle2.jpg">

    <p>
      handles
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing an image while click is held](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414279/changing-an-image-while-click-is-held)

Comment: Why not use ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to below.

```
$('.product_category_item div').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('.main_image').hide(); 
   $(this).find('.hover_image').show();
}, function(){
   $(this).find('.main_image').show(); 
   $(this).find('.hover_image').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was it. I hadn't thought of using `find()` function

Comment: Welcome. Yeah, without `this` it gets all elements matching the selector throughout the DOM. Also you can keep hover images hidden bydefault `.hover_image {display:none}`